# Indexing into std::array of std::array

Tags: c++, stdarray

I have some confusion about indexing of an array of arrays in C++:

I have:

```
array<array<int, SIZE_INNER>, SIZE_OUTER> arr;
```

When I do indexing, I assume the following:

```
arr[outer_index][inner_index]
```

So, `outer_index` into the array with `SIZE_OUTER` comes first, and the inner index then comes second.

Is that true?

Comment: yes thats true :)

Comment: See [Multi-dimensional arrays in C++11](http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2011/10/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c11.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Think like this: `arr[o]` accesses the o-th element of `arr`. The fact that the element is an array too doesn't change much.

Subsequent calls to `operator []` access elements returned by previous calls.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Let break it down a little

```
array<int, SIZE_INNER>
```

Is going to create an array of size SIZE_INNER.  Now you wrap that array in

```
array<array<int, SIZE_INNER>, SIZE_OUTER> arr;
```

So the inner array is your "column" and the outer array is your "row".  Just like with plain 2d arrays.

When working with the `[]` operator the one farthest to the right is for the inner most array.